# How to resolve "global evaluation not supported" in dart on vs code

Tags: dart

I'm unable to get input values entered using console. Whenever I'm using readLineSync() function, it results in an error saying "Global Evaluation not Supported".
I've been trying finding another function to do the same but left with only readLineSync().

```
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
  print("What's your name?");
  var name = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Welcome back user: $name");
}
```

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. Can you check that this is the exact code you are running, and say how you run it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception "Global evaluation requires a thread to have been loaded" on VSCode when reading values with Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71946458/exception-global-evaluation-requires-a-thread-to-have-been-loaded-on-vscode-wh)