# Exception "Global evaluation requires a thread to have been loaded" on VSCode when reading values with Dart

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to run a Dart code like that on VSCode:

```
import "dart:io";
void main() {
  print("Input a number");
  int numA = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  print("The number is $numA");
}
```

However, after printing "Input a number" for the user input a number (duh), the program freezes with the message *Global evaluation requires a thread to have been loaded*:

[image: Exception when reading values]

The same program runs fine everywhere, e.g., [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-dart-online/) and IntelliJ. Any clue of what is happening, folks? No thread here on Stackoverflow provided an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default applications run in the Debug Console, where the input is used as a REPL to evaluate expressions. If you want to interact with `stdin` for the process, you'll need to set the app to run in the Terminal.

You can do this with a [launch configuration](https://dartcode.org/docs/running-in-terminal/) that includes:

```
"console": "terminal",
```

Or, you could set the [dart.cliConsole](https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/#dartcliconsole) setting in VS Code:

```
"dart.cliConsole": "terminal"
```

Comment: Sharp answer! I've noted that if you run your dart program by using the context menu (the one that pops over the "main" function), VS Code ignores the settings in the launch.json file - that's why I always started my program in the debug mode. You have to use F5 or CTRL+F5 to run it under launch.json settings or, as you said, configure properly the cliConsole key with the "terminal" value instead of "debugConsole". Thanks!

Comment: By default yes, Run/Debug CodeLens links use their own default launch configurations. However, if you add `"templateFor": ""` to your launch config it should be used for a template for the CodeLens links (see https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-34/#debugger)

Answer (score 8):

All you need to do is change `dart:cli` console https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDlc1.png

1.go to extensions
2.dart extension settings .
3.manage settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynozr.png
4.In settings scroll down to "dart:cli" st it to terminal.