# How do I fix problem with data input (Dart)?

Tags: dart

My code:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  print("Enter your name:");
  String? name = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Hello, $name!");
}
```

**UnimplementedError: Global evaluation not currently supported.**

Error(IDE: VS Code):

[image]

How I can fix that problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception "Global evaluation requires a thread to have been loaded" on VSCode when reading values with Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71946458/exception-global-evaluation-requires-a-thread-to-have-been-loaded-on-vscode-wh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- this `error` occurs when you try to run Dart code that includes input from the standard input (stdin) in an environment that doesn't support it, such as an IDE's debug console.
- One option is to run your code in a `terminal` or `command prompt`. Navigate the file and Run your Dart code using the Dart SDK. Assuming your Dart file is named main.dart

> `dart main.dart`